# Flyway migrate doens't run in AWS EC2 userdata powershell script

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, flyway

I have placed flyway migrate command in a powershell script as I want it to run automated once i create an EC2 windows box. Powershell runs the "flyway migrate" command, but actually flyway isn’t executing anything. And I’ve proven this by outputting a file when the flyway migrate function was executed. See attached the NoOutput png.
[Click here to see screenshot NoOutput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOgiO.png)

Then If I manually execute the command, it works as expected. What am I doing wrong? What can be the cause of not running from powershell? I don't think it is powershell to be blaimed for. And if it is, what syntax should i use? I am actually thinking of creating an .exe file with the flyway.cmd migrate :)))--bit of over thinking i guess.

[Click here to see screenshot WithOutput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtfic.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try running flyway as follows:

```
&$FlywayDir\flyway.cmd | Out-File C:\filename.txt
```

> The ampersand (the 'and' sign) here tells PowerShell to execute that command, instead of treating it as a cmdlet or a string.
>
> From this blog: http://edgylogic.com/blog/powershell-and-external-commands-done-right/